# posgresql 10 How to assigned filtered sum result to different variables?

Tags: postgresql, plsql

i try, within the same query from same table, assign the result of a sum based on different filter criteria.

Here my table toto
istrue|weight|
------|------|
false |0.1500|
true  |0.1319|
true  |0.0002|
false |0.0001|
true  |0.0435|

A simple select give me the expected result.....

```
select (select sum(weight) from toto where istrue) as istrue,
    (select sum(weight) from toto where not istrue) as isnottrue;
```

```
|istrue |isnottrue |
|-------|----------|
|0.1756 |0.1501    |
```

now i want to assigne those 2 columns to 2 variables....

```
DO $$
declare
    var_istrue numeric(6,4) := 0.0;
    var_isnottrue numeric(6,4) := 0.0;
begin
    select (select sum(weight) from toto where istrue) as istrue,
            (select sum(weight) from toto where not istrue) as isnottrue 
        into var_istrue, 
            var_isnottrue;
    raise notice ' isTrue=%',var_istrue;
    raise notice ' isNOTTrue=%',var_isnottrue;
end $$;
```

and get the expected result:

```
00000:  isTrue=0.1756
00000:  isNOTTrue=0.1501
```

but i wonder if their is not a more efficient(faster) way to get the same outcome.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a single query/pass over the table with conditional aggregation:

```
select
    sum(weight) filter (where istrue) as istrue,
    sum(weight) filter (where not istrue) as isnottrue 
from toto
into var_istrue, var_isnottrue;
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, you save my day, i didn't knew this syntax.